# Updating an association between existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, model-associations

I have a users table and services table:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services, through: :services_users
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :services_users
end
```

with the join table:

```
 create_table "services_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
   t.integer "service_id", limit: 4
  t.integer "user_id",    limit: 4
 end
```

I have a form to select a user and a service and I want to associate them,
the form selects a service then a user

and I have the following

```
user_dispatcher_path(user,service), method: :put
```

with a route

```
put "dispatcher" => "userrs#dispatcher", as: :dispatcher
```

In my users controller I have started

```
 def dispatcher
    ?
 end
```

then I am stuck:

I think I can use update_all of maybe I can save the two ids directly to services_users

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no activerecord model for ServicesUsers, try this

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@user.services << Service.find(params[:service_id])
```

If the user/house is not already present, use create. or better yet, use [find_or_create_by](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by)

alternate way to model your requirement.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association - This is exactly what you need. assemblies = services, parts = users.

Comment: Almost - I created  ServicesUsers model  - but got the no method error for create! so I made it an active record model and added a controller and now it is looking for a template -

Comment: On Second thought it seems to me that Rails should be taking care of the join table and I shouldn't need to access it directly

Comment: I have edited the answer to work without ServicesUser model. Let me know if this works